# Vue component Vuex option block feature

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

While reading [Vuex repository docs](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/tree/master/docs/en), I came across the following syntax:

```js
export default {
  template: '...',
  data () { ... },
  // NOTICE SYNTAX BELLOW
  vuex: {
    getters: {
      count: function (state) {
        return state.count
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Notice the syntax of `vuex` option block of the component.

When referencing to either the [official Vuex docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) or [official Vue 2 API docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/), the usage of `vuex` component option, smiliar to the one above, is not mentioned.

The only thing I understand about this block is (according to Vuex repository docs):

> Note the special `vuex` option block. This is where we specify what state the component will be using from the store.

What is the actual usage of `vuex` block? can it be used instead of [component binding helpers](https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#component-binding-helpers)? such as `mapGetters` and `mapState`?

Seems like the official docs are lack of docs about this feature.

I'd like to have further information about this feature, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It think it is pointing out the case that one can individually decide on a component basis whether vuex shall be used or not.

The initial example in the vuex docs injects the store on a global level into all Vue instances, meaning that all components have access to the store.

If you'd like to have more control over which component uses vuex you can go for a explicit declaration of using vuex - for each component individually by using the syntax you are referring to.